# gwt project: error in external library "cannot be abstract"

Tags: java, gwt

I'm building an application with gwt but after upgrading to gwt 2.6 I get this error message when I compile:

```
Compiling module it.twain.MYPROJECT
    [ERROR] Errors in 'gwtupload/client/DecoratedFileUpload.java'
        [ERROR] Line 358: Rebind result  'gwtupload.client.DecoratedFileUpload.DecoratedFileUploadImpl' cannot be abstract
```

Can someone explain to me what can I do to fix this?

Comment: You have to upgrade gwtUpload also to latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by downgrading the application to gwt 2.4.
I know this is not a real solution but at least the application compile with no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your migration you missed some "replace-with" from the module xml definition.

I got this error when I forgot to add this in my project:

```
  <replace-with class="com.vv.xui.client.DesktopClientFactory">
        <when-type-is class="com.vv.xui.client.IClientFactory" />
  </replace-with>
```